# Fire action in Backbone View after two events have been triggered

Tags: backbone-events

I understand how to bind an action in a Backbone View to an event trigger but, how can you fire an action watching the condition that two precise envets have been triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you can use jquery functionality like:

```
$.when(func1, func2).then(func3);
```

It acts like deffered and promise here.